# How to get the sent, received and round trip latency of a bot using discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have made a latency/ping command that displays the latency using `client.latency` method in discord.py, but i want to include the sent, received and round trip latency like this one:
[image]

Here is the source code for my bot and the current latency command. I am using app_commands.CommandTree() for the slash command that does the job.

````
import os
import discord
from discord import app_commands

TOKEN = 'BOT TOKEN'
GUILD_ID = 'GUILD ID' ''' GUILD ID must be of type int '''

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)  #FOR SLASH COMMAND


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot has connected to Discord.')

@tree.command(name='latency', description='latency command', guild=discord.Object(id=GUILD_ID))
async def command1(interaction:discord.Interaction):
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Bot Latency', color=discord.Color.dark_blue())
    latency_raw = float(client.latency)
    latency_ms = int(1000 * (round(latency_raw, 3)))
    embed.add_field(name='Client Latency', value=f'```{latency_ms}ms```', inline=True)
    embed.set_footer(text=f'Requested by {interaction.user}')
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)

client.run(TOKEN)
````

I tried looking for different functions within the discord.py module that could return the sent, received and round trip latency with no success.

I am using the latest version of discord.py (version 2.3.1) and PyCharm IDE to run my discord bot.